# Feed NSIS installer prompts from Chocolatey

Tags: nsis, chocolatey

I wanted to use Chocolatey to install [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org); since there's no package for it in the community feed, I chose to create my own package based on their official (NSIS) Windows installer.

I'm currently using the [`Install-ChocolateyPackage` commandlet](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-package)'s `-SilentArgs` parameter to hide the installer window:

```
Install-ChocolateyPackage `
   -PackageName $Env:ChocolateyPackageName `
   -Url "http://sourceforge.net/.../geoserver-2.14.0.exe" `
   -FileType "exe" `
   -SilentArgs "/S /D..."
```

However, the installer has several interesting prompts that e.g. give you the possibility to customize the web server's port number...

[image: Image: GeoServer's NSIS installer, prompting for a custom port.]

Is there a way to feed the fields of the installer from the command line, i.e. like `/D` for the installation path?

Comment: Pre add all of the stuff they ask for, it may bypass those settings. Even better is to create package parameters for them - https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-parse-package-parameters-argument. Check out the Git package for an example where this is done - https://chocolatey.org/packages/git.install

Comment: By pre-add, it means you may need to set registry settings, an INI file, or something else depending on what the installer does.

Answer (score 3):

NSIS itself only has built-in automatic support for `/NCRC`, `/S` and `/D=c:\foo\bar`, anything beyond that has to be specifically coded by the install author.

`/S` sets the installer mode to silent and skips all pages, it will only execute the `Section`s. `IfSilent` can be used to detect silent mode in your code.

Custom options support can be added to a installer by parsing the command line with the `GetOptions` macro from `FileFunc.nsh` and/or by using a answer file.

A answer file is usually just a .ini file with values the installer can read to change default values: `ReadIniStr $FooValue "$EXEDIR\mysetupanswer.ini" "Options" "Foo"`.

Comment: When saying _"IfSilent can be used to detect silent mode in your code."_ and _"Custom options support can be added [...]"_, you're referring to somethings happening _installer-side_ , nothing provided as a standard, right?

Comment: Yes, it's up the author of a specific installer to decide what silent means (other than just skipping all the pages)

Comment: Well, I guess the answer for me is that there is no way. :( Is there a standard way to get the accepted parameters from an installer, e.g. `theNsisInstaller.exe /HELP`?

Comment: The GetOptions macro can do that but the install author has to manually add the code. In your case, since the product is open source you can modify their installer and maybe even get your changes added to the official installer down the line.